# Полиморфизм в методах

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Изучаю c# поэтому возник вопрос про полиморфизм. Сам пробовал писать но успеха не добился поэтому спрашиваю у специалистов.
Возможно ли передавать в метод тип обьекта и обрабатывать соответствующую таблицу при помощи Entity framework. В метод будут передаваться классы. Пример кода чтобы вопрос был более понятен:

```
class SomeClass
{
   List<SomeType> SomeMethod(object modelClass)
   {
       List<modelClass> SomeItemsList = new List<modelClass>;
       SomeItemsList = db.modelClass.ToList();
       return SomeItemsList;
   }
}
```

То есть, я отправляю в метод тип класса чтобы получить данные из базы данных соответствующие этому классу. Функция вызывающая этот метод знает какие данные она получит а вот этот метод нет. Как научить правильно определять тип класса и получать соответствующие данные. Спасибо.

Comment: Вам надо почитать про Обобщения или Дженерики, потому как ваш пример очень ровненько ложится в случай List<T> where T class

Comment: У вас непонятный пример. Покажите, как вы бы хотели этот код _использовать_.

Comment: Нет, так Вы сделали, компьютер не поймет. Грубо, без использования мудреных слов (ссылка, указатель, алиас), - аргументом метода может быть либо объект существующий в памяти, либо его адрес в памяти. Следующий уровень абстракции это шаблоны функций и классам, применимые к любым (но при соблюдении ограничений :) ) заранее неизвестным типам, которые указываются в угловых скобочках. Принципиальное отличие шаблонов - они специализируются на этапе предкомпиляции, а методы классов исполняются уже в загрузочном модуле при исполнении программы.

Comment: На контексте вызываем Set<TEntity>, где TEntity ваш класс, описывающий таблицу

Comment: Всем спасибо, а особенно Bulson за наводку.Подружился с Дженериками, теперь кода гораздо меньше.